# Get Next/Previous (Sibling) Top Level Parent Page Id - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Question: Is there any possibility to get next/previous page id in wp_nav_menu in wordpress.

Example: I have navigation menu like this

```
Menu_Item_1  (ID = 5)
  >SubMenu_Item_1-1
  >SubMenu_Item_1-2

Menu_Item_2 (ID = 11)
  >SubMenu_Item_2-1
  >SubMenu_Item_2-2
```

If I am on the Menu_Item_1 or any of its child pages, the id of the next top level menu item ( Menu_Item_2 in this case) must be stored in a variable and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom walker to achieve this. [Here](http://www.kriesi.at/archives/improve-your-wordpress-navigation-menu-output) is a detailed explanation about it.

OR

Also, here is a possible workaround:

Edit nav-menu-template.php file which is under wp-includes folder.

Scroll down to line no. 114 which looks like:

`$output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $value . $class_names .'>';`

replace this line with:

`$output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $value . $class_names .' data-id='. $item->object_id .'>';`

This will add the original id's in all the `<li>` and will look like:

`<li id="menu-item-29" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-29" data-id="14">`

Here `data-id` is having the id that you required. You can use jQuery to get this id:

`targetId = $('#menu-item-29').attr('data-id');`

Note: these changes would be overridden once you update your Wordpress installation.